# Как правильно рендерить цилиндр/длинный прямоугольник?

Tags: оптимизация, opengl, графика

В ходе изучения OpenGL мы с другом вступили в дискуссию как лучше рендерить цилиндр (при этом меш для цилиндра создаем сами)

1. Нужно ли делить цилиндр на слои
2. На сколько слоев надо делить
3. Если нужно то в каких ситуациях
4. Как это влияет на скорость/качество отрисовки
5. Какие еще есть плюсы/минусы деления на слои

Comment: в этом "вопросе" содержится несколько вопросов. разбей его на более простые и задайте отдельно, а иначе нельзя будет дать хороший развернутый ответ.

Comment: Совет - Не занимайтесь оптимизациями раньше времени. Сделайте отрисовку независимой от остального кода и сможете заменить один вариант на другой без изменений в остальной программе.